# How to use ForeignKey get model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class hotel(models.Model):
    hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Sell(models.Model):
    hotel = models.ForeignKey("hotel")
    sell_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Orderform(models.Model):
    buy_choices = [(data.id+1, data.hotel_name) for data in hotel.objects.all()]
    buy_hotel_id = models.IntegerField(choices=buy_choices,default=1)

class Selled(models.Model):
    orderform = models.ForeignKey("Orderform")
    sell_id = models.IntegerField()
    sell_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

I want `sell_id` to use choices

```
buy_choices = [(data.id+1, data.sell_name) for data in hotel.objects.get(id=buy_hotel_id).sell_set.all()]
sell_id = models.IntegerField(choices=sell_choices,default=1)
```

but i don't konw how to get `buy_hotel_id`

I want use `hotel.objects.get(id=buy_hotel_id)`

Example

```
<hotel:1> have [<sell:banana>,<sell:apple>]
<hotel:2> have [<sell:grapes>,<sell:starfruit>]
```

if `buy_hotel_id` is `1`

want results `[<sell:banana>,<sell:apple>]`

I try `Sell.objects.all()`
get `[<sell:banana>,<sell:apple>,<sell:grapes>,<sell:starfruit>]`
This is not I want results

Comment: You wish to get a hotel's sell objects? question is very unclear

Comment: +1 to taesu, and in addition, I didn't understand why you're doing `data.id+1` (that will give you the wrong id, or even a non-existing one), and dynamic choices for fields are a bit more complicated than that. Look into `ForeignKey.limit_choices_to` and ModelChoiceField in forms.

Comment: Taking part of Paulo's answer, wouldn't `hotel.sell_set.filter(pk=1)` get the correct results for your example?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you are trying to do. Could you explain it better?
Wouldn't it be like this?

```
sell_choices = [(data.id+1, data.sell_name) for data in Sell.objects.all()]
sell_id = models.IntegerField(choices=sell_choices,default=1)
```

And be careful, you are filtering the objects in the time your Model is being defined, so it will be evaluated only once. The best approach would be to implement a function that filters the objects and place it on your model definition as a callable:

```
# somewhere in your code you define the filtering function
def my_filter():
    return tuple([(data.id+1, data.sell_name) for data in Sell.objects.all()])

# and place the callable in your choices
...
sell_id = models.IntegerField(choices=my_filter,default=1)
```

Comment: sorry,I am add explained my ask

Answer (score 0):

After the edit, what you want is:

```
hotel.sell_set.all()  # hotel is an instance of the Hotel model
```

You can refer to the [appropriate documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

> Django also creates API accessors for the “other” side of the
>   relationship – the link from the related model to the model that
>   defines the relationship. For example, a Blog object b has access to a
>   list of all related Entry objects via the entry_set attribute:
>   b.entry_set.all().

Where these are the `Blog` and `Entry` models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()


class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
```

As I said in my comment, that answers your immediate question, but you'll face other problems.

Comment: I want use in class model,how can i do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but as I said in my comment, having dynamic choices is a bit more complicated. Look for `ModelChoiceField`.